# Why does an IP address range scan not scan the 255 address by default?

Tags: networking, lan

The [LAN scanning tool for Mac that I am using](https://www.iwaxx.com/lanscan/) starts with a default scan range of `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.254` (presumably this changes dependant what C level IP the gateway is set to.

Is there a technical reason the scanning range isnt set to `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.254` (note the 0 not 1 at the beginning and 255 not 254 at the end) ?

Is the `x.x.x.0` and `x.x.x.255` address not commonly used for some reason ?

Comment: @Mokubai, the question you linked to was about *starting* the address with 0 or 255 (and the one answer about _ending_ with 0/255 is deleted)...

Comment: @JakeGould OP asked why the scan does not have 0 and 255 at end.

Comment: A basic Google search with show that in /24 networks it's the network address and broadcast address. :-/